# how to center the box in C?

Tags: c

ok now I need help on how to center my box, I tried many ways on solving it but didnt come up with the right one. I am still new at this sorry if it is confusing.

```
void box()
{
    int i, j, w=20, h=12;
    putchar(218);
    for(i=0;i<w-2;i++){
         putchar(196);
    }
    putchar(191);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<h-2;i++)
    {
        putchar(179);
        for(j=0;j<w-2;j++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        putchar(179);
        printf("\n");
    }
    putchar(192);
    for(i = 0; i<w-2;i++)
    {
        putchar(196);
    }
    putchar(217);
}
    int main()
    {
        gotoxy(30,0); printf("\nRobby Robot walks in a Cartesian plane.\n");
        box();
        gotoxy(30,5); printf("a. Orgigin\n");
        gotoxy(30,6); printf("b. Location\n");
        gotoxy(30,7); printf("c. Move\n");
        gotoxy(30,8); printf("d. Exit");
    }
```

Comment: Is this C or C++?  They are two different languages.  Neither standard version uses `gotoxy()`.

Comment: The center point, in one dimension, is `distance / 2`.  You may need to add in an offset after calculating the center point.  Another formula:  `left_position = (distance / 2) - (box_width / 2);`.

Comment: You probably need to use `gotoxy` before printing each row of the box.  BTW, you misspelled "Orgigin", I think it should be "origin".

Comment: `gotoxy` is neither standard C or C++. If I recall correctly it is a remnant of *turbo C*. If you are interested in a more portable solution, you may want to look at the `curses` or `ncurses` library.

Comment: im using DEVC++  and this is how i used                                             void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
 HANDLE hConsoleOutput;
 COORD coord;
 coord.X = x;
 coord.Y = y;
 hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsoleOutput, coord);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define SWIDTH (80) /* you may need to change this screen-width value */
void box()
{
    int i, j, w=20, h=12;
    putchar(218);
    for(i=0; i<(SWIDTH-w)/2; i++) putchar(' ');
    for(i=0; i<w-2; i++)
    {
        putchar(196);
    }
    putchar(191);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<h-2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<(SWIDTH-w)/2; j++) putchar(' ');
        putchar(179);
        for(j=0; j<w-2; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        putchar(179);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0; i<(SWIDTH-w)/2; i++) putchar(' ');

    putchar(192);
    for(i = 0; i<w-2; i++)
    {
        putchar(196);
    }
    putchar(217);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

SWIDTH = screen width in characters (number of characters that fit in one line on the terminal screen)

```
|<---------------------   SWIDTH   ---------------------->|
|                   ------------------                    |
|                  |                  |                   |
|                  <-  BOXWIDTH (W) ->                    |
|<- (SWIDTH-W)/2 ->                                       |
          ...
```

Comment: can you please explain what does the #define SWIDTH mean? It would really help on my future programming activities

Comment: `#define` is a preprocessor directive which in the program `defines` `SWIDTH` as `(80)`. Before the program is fed to the compiler, the preprocessor simply replaces the word `SWIDTH` with `(80)` wherever it finds in the program.